# Best way to store redis keys

Tags: c, ruby, database, redis, nosql

I am using Redis to store some information and detect changes in that information over time (for example, think users and locations).  What is the value to using a longer or shorter keyname?  Using a longer key is clearer, but is there much cost for memory or performance to using longer keyname?

Here are examples:

```
SET L:123456 "<name> <latitude> <longitude> ..."
HSET U:987654321 loc 123456 time <epoch>
```

or

```
SET loc:{123456} "<name> <latitude> <longitude> ..."
HSET user:{U987654321} loc 123456 time <epoch>
```

Comment: Hi Chuck, this comment is a bit off-topic. I noticed you haven't accepted any of my answers. This is perfectly fine ofcourse, but since you've posted quite a few, it'd be preferable for everyone at SO if you left a comment with a reason. It helps keeping SO a tidy place. You can also answer (and accept) your own answers. This way your questions don't pop up in 'unanswered' queries. All the best, TW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how you are going to use it.
If every byte counts, for example when you have to pay for each kB transferred to a cloud service, you can calculate the costs. The maths is simple; a byte is a byte 'on the wire'. Inside redis, for larger values it is equally simple. For smaller values, Redis does some memory optimization.

In your `HSET` example, you split out the members, which only makes sense if you need them separated from eachother most of the time. A better approach *-might-* be: `HSET user:data 987654321  '{"loc": "123456", "time": "2014-01-01T13:00:00"}'`. Separate keys/members 'cost' a lot more than longer strings, performance wise. You can even put a whole table or dataset in one member if it's only going to be used as one complete semi-static entity.

Speed and Size: There is a notable difference between *keys* and *values*.

*Keys:*
Shorter is generally more memory efficient as well as speed efficient. If you use a redis [Sorted Set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) you can even use 'numbers' as keys (sorted set 'members' plus 'scores'). I say 'numbers' because a score is technically a float64, but to be used as an ID it has to be between -999999999999999 and 999999999999999 including (that's 15 digits), without any fractional part. This can be really helpful, since Redis does fast and scalable O(log(n)) on-the-fly sorting of Sorted Sets (using skiplists, simplified).

*Values:*
The MsgPack format (uncompressed) takes up the least space, especially if you store the definitions once and the values many. JSON is a bit less memory efficient, but is ofcourse such a common IPC format that it should not be left out. Raw strings, character separated, fixed length (ugh), whatever your desire, it's possible to use. You can always compress your data before storing it in Redis. So far *memory efficiency*. When it comes to *speed*, it's less simple. If you want to use Lua server-side scripting (which you should), you can't do anything with compressed data. JSON and MsgPack can be deserialized, but only 'as a whole'. Which is fine in mosts scenarios. Most flexible is storing separate values (for example as members of a HSET), but this comes at a price as well (most of the time: too high a price). You also can combine all these. What we use most: a prefix of two or three delimiter-separated values, followed by a MsgPack payload.

My general advice is: start with using only HSET's and ZSET's, don't split out data that belongs together, use descriptive PascalCased names for your keys between 10-25 chars, use ':' if you need delimiters in your keys (namespaces), serialize as JSON (for simplicity, but code for easy switching to MsgPack), use Lua scripting (even if you don't know Lua, the subset you use in Redis is tiny).

I wouldn't worry about it too much in the startup phase of your project, you can always change it later on and do some A/B comparisons as soon as you have some interpolatable data.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: A side-note: I see you have 'C' as a tag. If you go for MsgPack and want to use it from C, I can recommend the excellent Cython implementation by Inada Naoki, which is mainly C and/or very easy to port. See [here](http://msgpack.org/). We found it easier to use (from C) than the official C implementation.

Comment: I have used Lua and am calling functions from my client code to evoke scripts stored in a keyspace ( :func:<funcname> ), and doing some simple server side lookups and joining.  Your answer has been helpful; I am looking for insight for key choices.

Comment: Okay, clear. Your question was: '_is there much cost for memory or performance to using longer keyname?_', and I think I answered that. What other insights are you after? Happy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Redis v3.2 is almost here, you should consider switching to the new geo hashing functionality: http://redis.io/commands/geoadd