# Redis: At what point is a lot of data too much?

Tags: redis, nosql

I've built a social graph in Redis using sets and hashes containing information about users, posts, interests, comments, messages, likes, blocks, flags, etc. Here's some examples:

Sets:  (`user:1:followers "3","5","9"`), (`post:11:likes "2","5","8"`)

Hashes: (`user:1 first_name "John" last_name "Smith" age "25"`), (`message:5 body "Hi"`)

My plan is to eventually save all of this information to disk. Bit by bit, I'm starting to realize how much potential data I could have on my hands. What if a post gets liked ten thousand times? Should the `post:85:likes` set really have 10,000 user ids? Will saving a lot of the data to the disk massively kill Redis' performance?

I know Pinterest does something similar [(source)](http://blog.gopivotal.com/pivotal/case-studies-2/using-redis-at-pinterest-for-billions-of-relationships), but my application and graph potentially contain a lot more data relationships than Pinterest's does. Is this too much for Redis? Should I consider switching to another key-value store like Dynamo that can potentially handle more data?

I apologize if I'm misinformed on anything. I'm still fairly new to Redis. I originally was drawn to Redis for its performance, but would this graph eliminate that advantage? I would appreciate any input, thank you!

**Update**: I realized that it would be very efficient in my case to serialize sets and store them as strings. I'm still facing a lot of potential data. What other methods, such as serializing, would help decrease my memory usage and not my performance?

Comment: Serializing to msgpack helps decreasing memory usage as well as increasing performance. If you want to handle a lot of data but don't exactly know how much: shard early. You might also want to read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547994/best-way-to-store-redis-keys/22548639#22548639)