# what is most optimal way to store an object in redis?

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis, hashmap

I have a class, which is modeled like this, all member variables are comprising of strings and  integers.

```
> class XYZ extends CFormModel
    {
    //Values required for rendering the Dashboard
    public $username;
    public $analysis_type;
    public $trace_selection;
    public $filter_phantoms;
    public $trace_oui_map;
    public $frame_min;
    public $frame_max;
    public $time_end;
    public $frame_range;
    public $time_range;
    //Other Values
    private $RETURNURL;
    private $PARAMS;
    private $connection;        // connection to db client
    private $database;          // handle to database
    private $col_trace_info;    // handle to trace_info collection
    private $col_csv;           // handle to csv collection
    ...
    ...
```

I want to ***store this object of this class in redis*** cache for performance improvements.
Solutions i have stumbled upon to is to use hashmaps..

```
Yii::app()->cache()->executeCommand("HSET", array("KEY"=>$hashMap, "FIELD"=>$key, "VALUE"=>$object));
```

My question is, is there a better way to store is object in memory, by using any other data structure or serialize it before storing, or something like that??

Comment: Hash maps are indeed the perfect fit for your needs in terms of Redis data types :) I know next to nothing re. Yii but perhaps you should look into an object mapper to do your heavy lifting here (unfortunately I'm not sure there's one in PHP). You could also look into just using serialize() and storing the entire thing as a string... or check out http://rediska.geometria-lab.net/ that is supposed to do objects' serialization.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Using an object mapper or [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) can indeed be useful, when you want a generalization layer. The downsides of an object mapper are: 1. more dependencies 2. often designed for a previous version of redis, so sometimes not optimal with regards to what redis can do now 3. if your new to redis, it helps to keep things simple and direct. redis.io is of such high quality (imo) that object mappers have trouble keeping up. I've put my recommendations below.

Comment: @TwBert I fully agree with the comment and your recommendations are spotless but do require deeper familiarity with Redis et al. (and thanks for all you've did in bringing lexical ordering into Redis BTW). My motivation for going in ORM direction was what you referred to as #3.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thank you for your kind words. I put #3 down as a _downside_ (__not__ using an ORM is more direct, plus easier to understand imo), but it's all debatable. It all depends on the preferences of the developer and the use case. Thx for bringing ORM into this thread, useful info for future SO readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hash Sets are not needed (nor preferred), if you need the *complete* object or record at retrieval in most of your scenario's. A Hash Set is like a mini-redis database inside Redis. Each key has overhead, and each member of a Hash Set has overhead.

I recommend this approach:

1. Serialize your data as [messagepack](http://msgpack.org/).
2. Use a Hash Set, but put a complete record in each member of that Hash Set. Only reason for using a Hash Set: This helps keeping things organized. Simple get/set would work as well.
3. If you want an numeric index 'almost' for free, use a Sorted Set instead of a Hash Set. You can use the score as an index. **2.8.9+:** Raw alphabetical index also supported: Put everything under score 0 , prefix your msgpack data with an alphabetical identifier/searchstring (plus a delimiter, `\t` is normally a good one) and use the new function [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex).
4. Pipeline your data
5. When doing bulk transfers, wrap the data again in a messagepack container, 1000 records a piece (indication), and let a server-side Lua script do the work for you.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548639/2759336) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redis-db/D4V6kDJNDsI)

Hope this helps, TW